# How to find cardinality of $C \backslash (B \cup D)$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $B, C, D$ be finite sets $|B|=|C|  $ where $|\cdot|$ is the cardinality of the set.

Show that
$$
|C \backslash (B \cup D)|=|B \backslash C| -|(C \cap D) \backslash B|
$$
where $\backslash$ is the set difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Zuy in the comment, I only have a proof for the case that $B$ and $C$ are finite sets:

By $|B|=|C|$, we have $|B\setminus C|=|C\setminus B|$.
Also, $C\setminus B$ is the disjoint union of $C\setminus (B\cup D)$ and $(C\cap D)\setminus B$. Thus, we have
$$|B\setminus C|=|C\setminus (B\cup D)|+|C\cap D)\setminus B|.$$
It has nothing to do with $|D|\leq |B|$.
[image]

In general, the equality can be disproved with $C=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=D=\mathbb{Z}^+$:
We have

- $|B\setminus C|=|\mathbb{Z}^+\setminus \mathbb{Z}|=|\varnothing|=0$,
- $|C\setminus (B\cup D)|=|\mathbb{Z}\setminus \mathbb{Z}^+|=|\{0\}\cup \mathbb{Z}^-|=\aleph_0$, and
- $|(C\cap D)\setminus B|=|\mathbb{Z}^+\setminus \mathbb{Z}^+|=|\varnothing|=0$.

Comment: $|B|=|C|$ doesn't imply $|B-C|=|C-B|. For instance, take $B=\mathbb N$ and $C=\mathbb N_{>0}$.

Comment: @Zuy, you are right. My proof assumed that the sets are finite.

Comment: @modnar: why $|B\setminus C|=|C\setminus B|$ when $|B|=|C|$?

Comment: @Sepide: Please consider the "role" of $B\cap C$ in $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in general. If $C$ is a strict subset of $B$ (for instance $B=\mathbb N$ and $C=\mathbb N_{>0}$), the left side equals $0$, while the right one is strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you for pointing out to a great assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to observe that the sets $C\setminus (B\cup D)$ and $(C\cap D)\setminus B$ form a *partition* of $C\setminus B$.

We know, then, that $\bigl|C\setminus (B\cup D)\bigr| = |C\setminus B| - \bigl|(C\cap D)\setminus B\bigr|$.

It suffices, therefore, to prove that $|C\setminus B| = |B\setminus C|$, which follows from $|B|=|C|$. The fact that $|D|\leq|B|$ seems useless.